# Questions about performing nonlinear regression

Tags: nonlinear-regression

1. If the r-value is low, and we can't observe any relationship from scatterplot (as shown in figure below), does it means that it is not needed to perform nonlinear regression? (My project is fixed to use nonlinear regression) 
   [image: ScatterPlot1]
2. If the predictor variable is categorical (Yes = 1, No = 0), does it means that it is impossible to perform nonlinear regression using this variable as predictor? 
   [image: ScatterPlot2]

3. Most of the statistic softwares (Minitab, SPSS) only take single predictor for nonlinear regression, is there any software that is able to fit data and perform nonlinear regression with multiple predictor variables? In other words, is there a software that is able to learn the data and produce a nonlinear regression model with multiple predictors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first case, $r$ (or really $r^{2}$) is a measure of the strength of a *linear* relationship between the variables, so it would have no bearing on your ability to use nonlinear regression (and perhaps is indicative that you should).

In the second case, there's no problem using categorical predictors in regression of any type.

In the third case, you should try R. You can specify any nonlinear function you like with as many independent variables as you like.

Comment: Sorry sir, my 3rd question is that I need a software that is able to learn the data and produce a function for me instead of I myself specify the function

Comment: R is able to do machine learning. Matlab might be a better option or one of the Python modules as they're more common